# Meteor using value returned by Method.call outside function scope

Tags: javascript, meteor

> In below code res is a 2 dimensional array contatining .csv data returned by server.

```
var result;
Meteor.call('parseFile', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
    } else {
        // success!
        alert(res[0][0]);
        result = res
    }
});
let longitude = result[0];
```

I am using above code. And the value stored in result variable is null.However, in alert the variable res has values stored in it. I searched online and they say this is due to some fibre thing and advised to use session variable. But, I am not able to get that correct also. So, my question is basically how to use the array returned by server stored in res variable to use outside the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic Asynchronous Call issue. See: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

The usual way is to place whatever instructions that depend on your async task result (like `let longitude = result[0]`) inside that task's *callback*.

Within Meteor client code, you can also write your instructions in a reactive scope (e.g. within a Blaze helper, or using [`Tracker.autorun()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) / Blaze template [`this.autorun()`](http://blazejs.org/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun), using a [Reactive Variable](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) for your `result`. That way, once it gets *set* by your `Meteor.call()`, your reactive scope will re-run, this time using the updated value.

Comment: I am very new to Meteor, I don't understand what you are saying.. Could you please tell me what changes I should do into the code.

Comment: Try the classic approach first (see the linked post)

Comment: I read that its related to ajax and also nowhere its written how to access out of the scope of function. I think you can read this link https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-return-value-on-meteor-call-in-client/1277 so that you can get an idea.

Comment: However explanation of link is good.. I will try to read the link again if i get something.

Answer (score 0):

You should use reactive variables for this purpose [refer here for better insights](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html)

Answer (score 0):

See the below example
on a html file add the below with appropriate changes

```
<template name="test">
    <!-- Here is where you want your data -->
    <p>{{test}}</p>
</template>
```

on the js file add the below

```
Template.test.onCreated(function() {

  this.test= new ReactiveVar();

  Meteor.call('parseFile', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      // Set data into a reactive variable
      this.test.set(res);
    }
  });
});

Template.test.helpers({
  test: function() {
    // Helper will automatically rerun on method res
    return Template.instance().test.get();
  }
});
```